# How to use Parameter in Jenkins Bulk Builder Plugin?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

How and where can I access the parameter setting in Jenkins Bulk Builder Plugin.

I want to retrieve that value in windows batch.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install Jenkins Bulk Builder Plugin from mange plugins section. Then it will be automatically add the following section to Jenkins home.
[image]

then go inside and click on "Parameterized build" check box under Build options.

[image]

then put you parameters as follows

[image]

By default it will only support sting parameters. Then press build to start builds.